# No executable code found at line

Tags: java, maven, build, intellij-idea, maven-assembly-plugin

I am getting this message "No executable code found at line" when doing a remote debug from IntelliJ ver 12. This is a Java application. It is using maven for building the war. Not sure where to make the change in order to do the debugging properly.

Answer (score 5):

You need to ensure that sources in editor are in sync with the classes on the server. Classes must be compiled from exactly the same sources with the debug option enabled for the compiler.

Note that your classpath may be configured incorrectly and include some old version of the classes that you are trying to debug. It may also include different versions of the same class (like one from the `.jar`, another from `classes`) and JVM will load not the one you need.

Comment: Thanks @crazycoder, but I am did the build from IntelliJ. Then deployed it to local tomcat server. From IntelliJ, I started the remote debug. But it is not going to the correct breakpoint during the debugging.

Comment: Please share a sample project and provide the steps to reproduce the problem.