# Android studio omits breakpoints

Tags: android, android-studio

When I'm trying to debug application using android studio, I set some breakpoints in the IDE and after starting the debugger I've got an info on every single one breakpoint (in the baloon):

```
Warning : No executable code found at line ...
```

It looks like the message appears when the application reaches first BP.
Just to be clear - I have executable code in those lines like String s = "asd";

Comment: if this is unused variable it is possible this code to be ignored by the compiler, so basically it really don't exist.

Comment: Nope... I'm trying to debug important things :)

Comment: Do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466262/no-executable-code-found-at-line or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591662/cannot-set-java-breakpoint-in-intellij-idea help you? There may be other SO questions that are relevant.

Comment: I have had the same problem... This solved it for me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179748/the-first-line-breakpoint-works-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you debug on device or on emulator? If device then try to switch back to Dalvik from ART
[The first line breakpoint works only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179748/the-first-line-breakpoint-works-only/20203066#20203066)

Answer (score 15):

In my case a Build - Clean Project did help.

Answer (score 13):

set the minifyEnabled to false:

1. From the project section select the project
2. Right click on project and click open module settings
3. select the module you are running and from Build Type set the Minify Enabled to false

Comment: I had the same problem with the breakpoints not working in the middle of a method. One line of code was fine, and the breakpoint icon had a "checkmark" in it, but the next point had an "x" in the icon and gave the warring of "no executable code". I checked the Project Structure and the Build Type had already defaulted to "false", but I set it to false again and clicked OK.

Comment: It is really important to check minifyEnabled setting in build.gradle

Answer (score 7):

Try to insert the next snippet code into the android{} block on the app build.gradle file:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false //<---- THIS FIX THE PROBLEM
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'pro
guard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
```

Comment: Great bro you save my time.

Answer (score 1):

Responding to user3167086's post -

I had the same problem with the breakpoints not working in the middle of a method. One line of code was fine, and the break point icon had a "check mark" in it, but the next point had an "x" in the icon and gave the warring of "no executable code". I checked the Project Structure and the Build Type had already defaulted to "false", but I set it to false again and clicked OK.

For those using Android Studio 1.5 like I am, the complete procedure - using the main menu - is to 
select **File -> Project Structure**. 
Then select your "**App**" module on the left, and then the "Build Types" tab across the top. 
Make sure you have "**Debug**" selected and not "release" on the left (you should see this at the top of the right hand column too) and then set **Minify Enabled to FALSE**.

Comment: This works for me. Minify was true;
Since I have a tablet with Intel inside, didnt find "runtime" options in developer mode to switch Dalvik

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use a "Debug" build variant - otherwise breakpoints don't work.

Comment: Amen. But for external jni-build the debug variant does not produce separate library outputs, and you must select the 'release' variant. This case is solved by adding "debuggable true" to the modules gradle config (under 'release'). Should probably be removed when done.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error message in a pop-up over the dreaded breakpoint with an X in it, in Android Studio's "stable" version 2.1.2 (Gradle: 2.10, Android Plugin: 2.1.2), and the fix was to simply hit the red 'stop' button on the current run session in Android Studio.
I have no idea how the current run session could interfere with setting a break point in source (I have everything under 'Instant Run' unchecked), but this worked for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

For the future:

In my case **ALL** lines of code were unavailable for debugger. Solution for my problem was **disabling jack** to avoid creation of intermediate code.

These lines in my **gradle.build** were to blame:

```
defaultConfig {
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
```

I turned jack options on several months earlier and then switched back to Java7 forgetting about how my application works. No suprisde Android Studio couldn't find matching code.

I hope it will help.